# Memory Profiler reporting error upon profiler-report

Tags: commands, profiler

After calling `profiler-report` after doing `profiler-start` and selecting `mem` I get the following error:

```
maphash: Wrong type argument: number-or-marker-p, unbound
```

Any Idea why?

Comment: same issue here.